# Decrease clickable area for JComponent

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener, jcomponent

So, in my program I have several JComponents laid out on a map. The JComponents are filled with fillArc's, meaning that the actual arc is only covering lets say 25% of the JComponent. Is there any way to decrease the clickable area for the JComponent so it better matches with the fillArc? Right now you are able to click outside the arc and still interact with it...

Thanks in advance!

Should probably clarify that the fillArc is shaped like a triangle and that is a requirement for this assignment!

Comment: Did you try http://java-swing-tips.blogspot.be/2008/07/create-round-image-jbutton.html ?

Comment: Thats not quite what I'm looking for unfortunately :/

Comment: @LinusLindvall, `Thats not quite what I'm looking for unfortunately` in what way? The solution is that your arc should be represented by a Shape object. Then you override the `contains(...)` method to see if the mouse points is contained within the Shape. Your code uses an Arc, the example code uses an oval. The concept is the same.

Answer (score 0):

There is a general solution that I wrote to handle this issue located at: http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/shape/

This solution uses `Area`s for a standard solution for interacting with Shapes in a Component. In particular, you should look at AreaManager, and the MouseListener defined there.